# Any prime of the form $3k+1$ is also of the form $6k+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

This question is from a book, and my approach is that need consider properties of the two numbers. Both are odd as must be $\gt 2$.

The value $3k+1$ is already given, and need consider the second form. This form $6k+i, \exists i, \forall k \in \mathbb {N}$ can be: $6k+1, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+4, 6k+5, 6k$. Only $6k+1, 6k+5$ can be possibly prime, rest must be composites.

But, it seems more like a typo in the question that both are having the same variable $k$.

Comment: I suppose $k$ is taken here as a dummy variable.

Comment: the explanation is that the question is talking about 'form', it isn't saying that if a number equals 3k+1 then it also equals 6k+1, kust that it could be 'formed' from a suitable integer k in each case (not the same integer in each case).  if 3k + 1 is prime, you can show that 3k is even, so it is also some 6k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a prime $p$ has the form $3k+1$, can $k$ be odd? No, because then $3k+1$ would be even, and $2$, the only even prime, is not of the form $3k+1$. Therefore, $p=3\times(2k')+1=6k'+1$, for some integer $k'$.

Answer (score 5):

You are misled by mathematical shorthand.

$p$ is *of the form* $3k+1$ means that you can find a $k$ with $p=3k+1$.

$p$ is *of the form* $6k+1$ means that you can find a $k$ with $p=6k+1$.

The point is that the $k$ you find in the first statement doesn't have to be the same number as the $k$ from the second statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, obviously, the variable isn't same.

You can also prove this considering two cases : $k$ is either even or odd.

If it's odd, then it'll be of the form $k=2n+1 \implies 3k+1=6n+4$, which can't be a prime since $6n+4$ is divisibile by $2$. Hence, $k=2m$.

Therefore, ant prime $p=3k+1$ will also be of the form $6m+1$